# AWS Quicksight cannot connect to Aurora PostgreSQL in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-quicksight, aws-aurora-serverless, private-subnet

I am trying to connect to Aurora PostgreSQL database in a private subnet from QuickSight. I created the VPC connection in the Quicksight dashboard and when i try to create a new analysis using Aurora as the data source i get the following error -

```
sourceErrorCode:GENERIC_SQL_EXCEPTION
sourceErrorMessage:The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

The auth type is username/passwd. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so Quicksight does not support `aurora-postgresql14` as of now. Downgrading to 13.8 worked out.